# entire activerecord object printing to screen when I try to interate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

FYI I am trying ftp do this in a custom (not directly associated with a model) activeadmin page.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Category Selection" do
  content do
    categories = ItemsCategory.all

    categories.each do |item|
      puts item
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is I will iterate over the object and do what I need to to do... and I can. However, I the entire object is being printed to screen before everything else.

```
[#<ItemsCategory id: 2, name: "test 2", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-04 17:58:46", updated_at: "2014-03-04 17:58:46">, #<ItemsCategory id: 3, name: "test 3", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-04 17:23:23", updated_at: "2014-03-04 17:23:23">, #<ItemsCategory id: 5, name: "test 4", parent_id: 3, created_at: "2014-03-06 17:48:25", updated_at: "2014-03-06 17:48:25">, #<ItemsCategory id: 1, name: "NEW test EDITED", parent_id: nil, created_at: "2014-03-04 17:57:21", updated_at: "2014-03-10 20:50:10">]
```

What's causing that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but this was happening for me when I had <%= %> on my iteration. It should be <% %>.